# I need cesession.jar file?

Tags: business-objects-sdk

Business Objects Enterprise : Need of cesession.jar file

I need a **cesession.jar file.** I searched many sites but am unable to get it from any website.So can u please provide the link which contains **cesession.jar** file. I need it very urgent.

My project code depends on it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If one of the answers helps you, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to [buy it](http://store.businessobjects.com).
If you think you should have a copy, then you can ask on the [SAP forum](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/forum.jspa?forumID=316).
You can also check their [Knowledge Base](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/sdklibrary) which might have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It is provided in the standard Business Objects XI install. It can be found in <Your Business Objects Install Dir>\common\4.0\java\lib, along with all of the other jars needed to interface with Business Objects Enterprise.

If you do not have a valid install of Business Objects, then I recommend following one of yakatz recommendations.